# How to stop a PIR sensor from sending high output when there's no motion

Tags: arduino

My intention is a program a system that turns on at a certain time and also turns off at a particular time. But the problem I'm facing is that each time it gets to the scheduled time to turn on the sensor starts sensing motion even when there's no motion for a few seconds after that it goes back to normal. Normal in the sense that it stops sensing motion when there's no motion. I ran a basic motion dection code using PIR sensor and led just to check if the sensor is working properly, it worked out fine so I don't really know why I'm still getting that error.
Please how can I eliminate this error cus I have very little knowledge on how to program an Arduino.

```
DS3231 rtc(SDA, SCL);
String textForSMS;
int PirSensor = 6;
int LedSensorPin = 13;
int Buzzer = 11;
int LedPowerPin = 9;
int Power   =  6; // 5V of sensor connected to pin6
int val     =0;

const int OnHour = 13;
const int OnMin =  38;
const int OnSec = 0;

const int OffHour = 13;
const int OffMin = 40;
const int OffSec = 0;


void setup() {
  
Serial.begin(9600);
rtc.begin();
Serial.println("Logging Time Completed ");
pinMode(PirSensor, INPUT);
pinMode(Buzzer, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LedSensorPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LedPowerPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Power, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);
digitalWrite(PirSensor, LOW);

//Wait for Syst3m to get ready
for(int x=0; x<27; x++){
        digitalWrite(LedPowerPin,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(LedPowerPin,LOW);
        delay(500);
        
    }
  //system ready
     for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
        digitalWrite(Buzzer,HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(Buzzer,LOW);
        delay(500);
        
    }
}

void loop() {
  
t = rtc.getTime();
Serial.print(t.hour);
Serial.print("hr, ");
Serial.print(t.min);
Serial.print("min. ");
Serial.print(t.sec);
Serial.print("sec");
Serial.println(" ");
delay(1000);

while(t.hour == OnHour && (t.min >= OnMin && t.min<=OffMin)){
    

analogWrite(Power, 255);       // Turn ON the Sensor

val = digitalRead(PirSensor); 
if ( val == HIGH){
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);   
  delay(500);
            }
  else{
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);   
        }
              t = rtc.getTime();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PIR sensor like the HC-SR501 will not immediately switch back to "low". It will switch to "high" once motion is detected and sustain the output for around 10 seconds.

In my applications I usually use multiple sensors, for example a PIR motion sensor combined with a camera. Once the PIR triggers, the application will start checking for motion inside the camera picture.

Comment: I don't really have problems with the sensor switching from one state to another. The problem is that when it gets to the time scheduled for the sensor to start sensing motion it immediately sends a high output without detecting any motion, 2 to 3 times after then it begins to work as expect

Comment: This should not happen, two things you could check:

- Try using another sensor in case your current sensor is faulty
- Check if you need a pullup resistor on your input pin (or use input_pullup)

Comment: Still the same problem. Could it be that the sensor doesn't have enough time to calibrate?

Comment: Try putting a cardboard tube around the sensor and observe the current when you switch on the sensor. If you still get the high signal within the first 30 or so seconds then you may indeed need a “warmup” period.